# Asynchronous AJAX call problem

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have a jquery Ajax call function that I use to submit form to database to save.
Also use that to get data from server and show to the user.
When I post\save form data, I must show a result of the post to the user whether there was an error or not.

Everything works fine if I run in synchronous mode. I get the data if I want or get the result after posting using this single method.

But it seems not working in async mode.

How do I pass the data back to the caller? The web service returns the data correctly.
See the alert() I have. It shows me the data.

How can I get data and show to user and post data and show result to user in async mode?
Do I need to create 2 separate functions one for get and other to post?

Here is the function:

```
function MakeAjaxCall(svr, webmethod_name, op, btn, rslt, bGetData) {
   var data = "";
   var args = '';
   var l = arguments.length;
   if (l > 7) { for (var i = 7; i < l - 1; i += 2) { if (args.length != 0) args += ','; args += '"' + arguments[i] + '":"' + arguments[i + 1] + '"'; } }

   var surl = "http://<myserver>/" + svr + '.aspx';
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: (op == "sync") ? false : true,
      url: surl + "/" + webmethod_name,
      data: "{" + args + "}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function ShowSuccess(res) {
         //alert('dfx res:'+res.d);//THIS SHOWS THE DATA FROM SQL CALL FINE
         data = res.d;
      },
      fail: function ShowFail(xhr) {         
         data = "ERROR";
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Where is it failing? Have you looked at your console output to see if it's even reaching the database? What other debugging have you done?

Comment: I get the data fine. How do I return to the caller?

Comment: @Proja How do you know the data isn't set correctly to your `data` variable after your success callback has run? Or is that not what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: data variable is getting set correctly. But the js function where I call MakeAjaxCall(), I need to have the data returned from web service (data variable gets it)

Comment: Basically the value of data variable needs to be passed to the caller of MakeAjaxCall()

Comment: @Proja That's not *asynchronicity*. That's *synchronicity*. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a callback function? E.g.,

```
function MakeAjaxCall(svr, webmethod_name, op, btn,
                      rslt, bGetData, callbackFunction) {
   //removed for brevity

   var surl = "http://<myserver>/" + svr + '.aspx';
   $.ajax({
      //removed for brevity
      success: function ShowSuccess(res) {
         //pass the data to the callbackFunction
         callbackFunction(res.d);
      },
      //etc.
   });
```

Then just pass the function name (or anonymous function) into the `MakeAjaxCall` function, like so:

```
//anonymous function
MakeAjaxCall(svrVal, somewebmethod_name, opVal, btnVal,
                      rsltVal, bGetDataVal, function(data) { alert(data); });

//named function
MakeAjaxCall(svrVal, somewebmethod_name, opVal, btnVal,
                      rsltVal, bGetDataVal, alert)
```

Comment: How will this return the data to the caller js method?

Comment: My point is that you should break up the caller method into a caller method and a callback method. The caller does everything up to the execution of `MakeAjaxCall`, and the callback method gets called on success, and passed the data it needs to finish everything up.

Comment: So you are asking to pass a function as a callback when I call MakeAjaxCall().

Comment: @Proja If all else fails, try the `async` parameter in the `ajax()` call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Do you have a sample code which shows the named function working? Where should the named function to be defined? On the caller page, right?

Comment: You can pass the name of any function (declared in the page or included js files) or a pointer to any function (anonymous or named) as the callbackFunction. Just ensure that it takes the parameter(s) in the order that the `MakeAjaxCall` function passes them into the callbackFunction within the `success:` value.